# Apply CSS after selector on an "ID contains" selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

**EDIT:** Okay, so I have learned that you cannot apply pseudo elements to inputs as they are technically empty. What would be the best work around that would involve not changing the inputs? I'm open to jQuery options.

I currently have `[id*="Cost"]` to select all ID's that contain the word Cost which works perfectly fine.

I'm trying to add the following line `:after` each ID but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120707152654/bindingofisaac/images/e/e8/Small_Rock_Icon.png" alt="rocks" width="20" height="20">
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/Mgs4g/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">Shovel(
    <input id="shovelCount" type="text" value="0" onfocus="this.blur()" style="width:20px; border:none; text-align:center; background-color:transparent;" />):
    <input id="shovelBuy" type="button" value="Buy" onclick="javascript:shovel()" />
    <input id="shovelCost" type="text" value="15" onfocus="this.blur()" style="border:none; width:50px; text-align:right; background-color:transparent;" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    font:1em Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
.item input[type=text] {
    color:#fff;
}
input[type=button] {
    outline:0;
    border: 0;
    background:#333;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:70%;
    /* ... other rules ... */
    cursor:pointer;
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
    border-left:1px solid #111;
    float:right;
}
input[type=button]:hover {
    background: #444;
}
.item {
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding-left:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #222;
}
[id*="Cost"] {
    float:right;
    line-height:30px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
[id*="Cost"]:after {
    content: url('http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120707152654/bindingofisaac/images/e/e8/Small_Rock_Icon.png');
}
```

Comment: input text field does not support pseudo-elements, but there are some input fields do such as radio, checkbox,

Comment: Pseudo elements doesn't work for self-closing tags. Although there are hacks for img but not for inputs. Reason being that the self closing tags doesn't have any content and so no pseudo elements can be appended to them

Comment: The comments are correct. Remember that pseudo-elements become children of the element they belong to. How would that work with a self-closing element? As for radio and checkbox, I never understood why you can apply pseudo-elements to them (but I'd be lying if I said I never used them!)

Comment: So there is no possible work around?

Comment: @ChrisHardie - A [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/FaE3t/) tells me that pseudo-elements work on radio and checkboxes only in WebKit/Blink. What do you do for IE and FF?

Comment: Add `label` elements in your markup and style them

Comment: @Danield, if I were to do that, I may as well just manually enter the image onto each line that I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your "shovelCost" is an input, pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after` not supported in input's value, use something else instead, like `<span>`, if you want it editable, add a property named `cotenteditable`

```
<span id="shovelCost" contenteditable>15</span>
```

Comment: I don't need the box the be editable, although this may work when removing it.\

Comment: This ended up working, or atleast a variation of it.